# multiple ng-repeat with groupBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am puzzled on how to render this object using ng-repeat to achieve the desired outcome below.

```
    var object = [{'category':'A', 'subcategory': 'aa', 'status': 'expected', 'points':5},
                  {'category':'B', 'subcategory': 'bb', 'status': 'complete', 'points':10},
                  {'category':'C', 'subcategory': 'c1', 'status': 'expected', 'points':10},
                  {'category':'C', 'subcategory': 'c2', 'status': 'expected', 'points':5},
                  {'category':'C', 'subcategory': 'c3', 'status': 'complete', 'points':10},
                  {'category':'C', 'subcategory': 'c4', 'status': 'complete', 'points':15},
                  {'category':'D', 'subcategory': 'd1', 'status': 'complete', 'points':10},
                  {'category':'D', 'subcategory': 'd2', 'status': 'expected', 'points':15},
                  {'category':'E', 'subcategory': 'ee', 'status': 'complete', 'points':20}];
```

I would like to group the ones with like category, yet display each record individually.

HTML attempt:

```
    <table class"table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Category</th>
             <th>Status</th>
             <th>Points</th> </tr> </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in products | groupBy: 'category'">
              <td>{{key}}
                    <!--WANT TO ACHIEVE BELOW-->
                  <div ng-if="multipleLines">{{value.subcategory}}</div></td>

              <td ng-if="multipleLines"></td> <!--LEAVE BLANK IF MULTIPLE LINES OF SAME CATEGORY -->
              <td ng-if="multipleLines"></td> <!--LEAVE BLANK IF MULTIPLE LINES OF SAME CATEGORY -->
              <td ng-if="!multipleLines">{{value.status}}</td>
              <td ng-if="!multipleLines">{{value.points}}</td>
```

DESIRED RESULT:

[image]

Currently, controller only retrieves the data using promise. First of all, is it possible to achieve this outcome with this type of data using ng-repeat? If so, how?  If not, how would I go about separating the data so that I could achieve the desired table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a better way but I think below one will also work for you.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Category</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Points</th>
    </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in products | groupBy:'category'">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td ng-if="value.length == 1" ng-repeat-start="(k,product) in value">{{product.status}}</td>
      <td ng-if="value.length == 1" ng-repeat-end>{{product.points}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="value.length > 1" ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="product in value">
      <td align="right">{{product.subcategory}}</td>
      <td>{{product.status}}</td>
      <td>{{product.points}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y2ee6ccf/2/)

Comment: +1 for the fiddle. I haven't seen this many nested ng-repeats in all of my searches. It'll definitely be a point of reference for many people, including me.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to use the group with filter is:

```
<ul ng-repeat="key, value) in products | groupBy: 'category'">
  Group name: {{ key }}
  <li ng-repeat="product in value">
    player: {{ product.subcategory }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The way I had the group filter worked, but I couldn't achieve my requirement. I see the value of your approach in expanding the nesting. Thanks!